# Null value is stored as a real value in Realm Android

Tags: java, android, mobile, realm

I'm trying to make a registration for my app using Realm. But when I click on register button without adding any values in username and password textfields it consider them as real values and store them to DB!!

How can I avoid this?

Here's my code:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regUserEditText);
    final EditText pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regPassEditText);
    Button register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.regButton);
    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setUsername(username.getText().toString());
            user.setPassword(pass.getText().toString());

            Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
            RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.
                    Builder().
                    deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().
                    build();
            Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);

            Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
            RealmQuery<User> query = realm.where(User.class);
            query.equalTo("username",username.getText().toString());
            query.equalTo("password",pass.getText().toString());
            RealmResults<User> result = query.findAll();
            if(result.size()>0 && (result.isEmpty()== true))
            {
                Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Username is already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else
            {
                realm.beginTransaction();
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(user);
                realm.commitTransaction();
                Toast.makeText(Register.this,"User registered..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

I solved it by adding the following code after setting the username and password and before configuring Realm lines..

```
String checkUser = username.getText().toString();
String checkPass = pass.getText().toString();

if (checkUser.matches("") || checkPass.matches("")) {
    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "You did not enter a username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
```

I hope you find it helpfull!

Thank you guys!

Comment: I tried to avoid it by adding isEmpty() method to my condition..

Comment: You should check your fields before save into db

Comment: @an_droid_dev How?

Comment: `result.size()>0 && (result.isEmpty()== true)` this is **always false** and should just be `!result.isEmpty()`.